# Creating in-house shared Java libraries with Quarkus

Tags: shared-libraries, quarkus

Does creating in-house shared libraries in Quarkus require using the Quarkus extension stuff to get the AOT compiling benefit when using the in-house shared libraries in my Quarkus projects? It would be great if there was specific documentation and examples of developing in-house shared libraries in Quarkus.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

An extension is the recommended way of achieving that. They can be more or less complex; in the simplest case, it could just add a few classes from the shared library as beans so they're available for CDI injection. More complex extensions could dynamically inspect the code and adjust behaviour for a better in-house developer experience. (I say 'dynamic', except that it happens AOT, so it's actually static.)

I found these resources useful for getting started with extension writing, although it will depend on your particular use case:

- https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-aws-cloudwatch_extension/
- https://quarkus.io/blog/solving-problems-with-custom-extensions/